# Инициализация потока в конструкторе класса

Tags: c#

Хочу выполнить сохранение в файл в отдельном потоке. Инициализирую поток в конструкторе, но запускаю - в методе `UpdateDataFile`:

```
private Thread dataFileTransactionsThread;

public PeopleRepository() {
   people = getPeopleDataFromFile();
   dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateDataFile));
}

public void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntity> peoples) {
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Start();
    // сохранение в файл
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Suspend();
}
```

Мне выдаётся сообщение, что "Соответствующий делегату `ThreadStart` метод "UpdateDataFile" не перегружен". Что это значит и что следует делать?

Comment: Для начала - определитесь, кто кого запускает. У вас какая-то рекурсия написана.

Comment: Да, это так... Нужно, чтобы поток запускался перед началом сохранения файла и после него - сразу завершался. Дополнительный метод создавать?

Answer (score 1):

[`ThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) - это делегат, который ничего не принимает и ничего не возвращает.

```
public delegate void ThreadStart()
```

Функция `UpdateDataFile` принимает один параметр, поэтому не может быть использована в качестве `ThreadStart`.

Для решения нужно либо добавить перегрузку

```
public void UpdateDataFile() { ... }
```

Либо использовать лямбду, например так:

```
dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(()=> UpdateDataFile(...));
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Ничего не принимает, говорите... А [этот пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.2.php) работает, хотя в нём есть выражение `Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Count));`. Почему так?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, потому что в том примере `void Count()`, а у тебя `void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntity> peoples)`. Под не принимает и не возвращает имелся ввиду, сам тип делегата `public delegate void ThreadStart()`, а не его конструктор.

Comment: насчет этого понял... Подскажите пожалуйста, в случае с перегрузкой методов вариант метода без входных параметров можно оставить пустым? Я не совсем понимаю смысл перегрузки в данном случае, потому, возможно, задаю глупый вопрос по незнанию.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, я не понял вопрос

Comment: прошу прощения. Спрошу так: что должны содержать метод `public void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<BranchEntity> peoples)` и его перегрузка `public void UpdateDataFile()`? Какой из них должен, собственно, содержать код для сохранения файла c открытием и закрытием потока после сохранения?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ответ очевиден: тот который ты будешь передавать в конструктор `ThreadStart`, Тот и будет выполняться в потоке.

Comment: а второй тогда можно оставить пустым, так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66867/discussion-between-grundy-and-gurebu-bokofu).